# Software for choosing the best output?

Tags: database, data-analysis, simulation

I am looking for a software which helps to choose between alternatives. The circumstances connected to social innovation, and the goal is to choose the best social innovation action based on several input data such as statistical data, former best practices, achieved social innovation actions and other data what we can "upload" to the software, then we can weight these data based on the current social innovation action/decision-maker, and the software choose the best option from a database which contain a lot of former actions. I am not able to describe it better, because I was told to search a possible solution, software for this, but there is no more detail.
If anyone have any idea, or other possible solution, please let me know.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try researching "decision-making software". [1000minds](https://www.1000minds.com/) is the biggest in this space.